# External USB HDD is extremely slow in Debian

Tags: linux, usb, debian

I have a problem with write/read speeds of externall HDD connected via USB 3.0 bridge to my Debian - powered computer (actually, it's HP t5710 Thin Client). When I connect this HDD to my windows PC it works like a charm, and write/read speeds are as high, as I would suspect they will be. But, when I connect this disk to Debian machine (via USB 2.0 port, since there are no 3.0 ports on the machine) speeds are extremly slow (I'm talking USB 1.0 slow - maximum buffered disk read recorded with hdparm is about 1MB/sec). In my dmesg I found this:

```
[ 4580.436091] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[ 4580.643018] usb 2-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[ 4580.661116] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153
[ 4580.661148] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 4580.661164] usb 2-2: Product: AS2115
[ 4580.661180] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[ 4580.661196] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[ 4580.671480] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4580.680674] scsi4 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[ 4581.689044] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2115             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4581.705548] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 4581.719003] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[ 4581.725941] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4581.725965] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 4581.733157] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4581.779086]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4581.842995] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

I suspect, that second line (about not running @ top speed) indicates, that there is a problem. Unfortunately, since I am a total Linux noob I have no clue as to how to make it better. Quick googling did show up some results, but all of them were related to devices using some other driver (uhci_hcd or else). Could you help me, or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problems is the driver used, `ohci-pci`, which is [the earliest driver for USB ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)): it is in fact a USB1.1 driver as you correctly surmised. Its faster brethren are 'ehci-hcd' and 'xhci-hcd'. Why your system is not using one of those, I really do not know.

You should first of all update your system,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then check your kernel version,

```
 uname -a
```

and your Debian version,

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

and post them here, we may be able to offer more specific advice after seeing the output of these two commands.

In any case, you may try to force your system:

```
 sudo modprobe -r ohci-pci
 sudo modprobe ehci-hcd
```

or

```
 sudo modprobe xhci-hcd
```

for USB3.0.

P.S.: don't you think there is a contradiction here?

> connected via USB 3.0 bridge to my Debian - powered computer
>
> via USB 2.0 port, since there are no 3.0 ports on the machine

Comment: By USB 3.0 bridge he means the SATA/USB adapter.

Comment: Instead of the forceful modprobe after boot, he should instead have something like this in `/etc/modprobe.d`: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/modprobe.d.usb-load-ehci-first?h=packages/filesystem, only if he is with a pre-3.12 kernel though: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=05c92da0c52494caf97d58be1b05b1f95a79ce4e

Comment: @TomYan I am not sure he has `e/x-hci`: on my systems I cannot even find ohci, so why does he still have it? I think he may have an incredibly old system, which needs some updating.

Comment: It isn't on your system simply means you/your distro no longer include the driver when building the kernel.

Comment: @TomYan That's why I am wondering which kernel siy is suing.

Comment: thanks for your help. right now I am @ work and do not have access to my  computer to check it out - will do it today's evening. as to old system - that is unlikely, as I installed it just about a week ago, and got if from Debian official site.
about your PS - I ment, that the bridge I am using is, in fact USB 3.0 bridge, but computer only offers USB 2.0 ports.

Comment: OK, my debian version is 8.3, and `uname -a` returned `Linux lamp-serv 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) i686 GNU/Linux`. Your suggestion to force system to use specific driver did not work - when I executed those commands hdd wasn't even detected by system...

Comment: sorry to flood comments page like that, but actually your suggestion to force system to use specific driver did work, but I had to reboot the system - right now, HDD is "served" with proper driver, and write/read speeds are USB 2.0 family, rather than 1.0! Thanks for your help!